# Value returning false when I am trying to mimic keystrokes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script and need to mimic some keystrokes after a new dialogue box pops up. When I get to this function block, powershell returns "False" and does not do the 'keystrokes.' I feel like I'm not making it to the next window.

```
    function ats{
      $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
      cmd /c C:\location\location\ats.exe
      $wshell.AppActivate('Administrative Tool Suite (ATS)')
      Sleep 1
      $wshell.SendKeys('TAB')
      sleep .5
      $wshell.SendKeys('TAB')
      sleep .5
      $wshell.SendKeys('TAB')
      sleep .5
      $wshell.SendKeys('TAB')
      sleep .5
      $wshell.SendKeys('~')
    }
    ats
```

Comment: in your case keys will send once you close the ats.exe.  Try with notepad.exe. it will send the keys once you close the notepad..

Comment: To solve this you need to open exe in other thread and send keys through main thread or different thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell is waiting to exit the exe in command. So you need mechanism that run the exe and execute the other commands parallel.

Just change the line :

```
start-job { cmd /c notepad.exe }
```

It will start new thread to open notepad and your further code will executed parallel. It sends keys to notepad.

If you want to send `tab`   then you have to use powershell escape character like **`t** .